# Why does /usr/local/bin not exist on my (Ubuntu 16.04) system?

Tags: 16.04, directory-structure

I've just reinstalled Ubuntu 16.04 on my machine, and I'm in the process of installing everything I had installed previously. This includes a few programs that I put in /usr/local/bin, but that directory doesn't seem to exist:

```
$ ls -A /usr/local
etc  games  include  lib  man  sbin  share  src
```

I don't remember explicitly creating /usr/local/bin on my old install, and yet it existed there. Why doesn't it exist by default, and how did it come to exist on my previous installation?

Comment: A few months ago installing `16.04.1` or `16.04.3` (can't remember) the directory was created by default. Were you using `16.04.4`?

Comment: I don't recall ever creating a `/usr/local/bin` directory is a Debian derivative.  It's the same with the Raspberry PI.  I believe I recall creating it back in the 90's before I switched to Ubuntu (Debian).  I previously had used, SCO Unix, Slackware and Redhat.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix yep, 16.04.4 (I only downloaded it about a day ago).

Comment: Sounds like a 16.04.4 bug or undocumented feature to reduce number of dirs...

Answer (score 18):

`/usr/local/bin` and other default folders such as the ones you mentioned and also `/opt` and `/mnt` are created during a normal Ubuntu installation.  By default the folders are empty.  If you don't have the folder, it simply means it has inadvertently been removed.

This is easily rectified just by creating the folder:

```
$ sudo mkdir /usr/local/bin
```

You can proceed to install your previously installed programs just as you normally would have, if the directory had not been deleted, after recreating it.

**And more directly to your questions:**

- Why doesn't it exist by default?
  It is created by default during installation.
- How did it come to exist in your previous installation?
  It's part of the default directory structure which was created during installation.

Comment: Interestingly, there seems to be no package actually owning /opt or /usr-local...

Comment: @rackandboneman I don't understand your comment.  Folders are not owned by packages.  They are owned by the creator of the folders.  There are some special conditions where special access is given to some folders and the user and group owner is specifically set to accommodate those conditions such as `/var/lib/mysl`, `/var/spool/rsyslog` and a few others.  Those are exceptional conditions.  The normal condition is that system-wide folders are owned by `root` and a user's personal folders are owned by the user... not a package.

Comment: "owned" as in maintainer responsibility ("dpkg -S"-syness) , not unix ownership...